Custom Picturebox with shape drawing and editing
I wrote this component to rendering the streaming of a Camera. Above the streaming, the user can draw one or more shapes (managed with an interface). The available shapes are:

Point
Rectangle
Ellipse
Polyline

In addition to drawing shapes, the user can select one and change the size and the position. The user can also see the hottest spot of the image which will then continuously move within the image.
The image is continuously updated and is handled by the event: UpdateRadiometricImage
This is my full code of the component:
using Imager.IRBinding;
using Imager.Services;
using Imager.Shapes;
using Imager.Types;
using Imager.Utils;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.Expressions;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Imager.Components
{
    public class RadiometricImage : PictureBox, IDisposable
    {
        // -------- PER IL DISEGNO
        internal string Serial { get; set; }
        internal List<IShape> Shapes = new List<IShape>(); // Forme permanenti
        
        internal List<IShape> SelectedShapes { get; set; } = new List<IShape>(); // Forme selezionate

        public ShapeType ShapeToDraw { get; set; } = ShapeType.None;
        public ModeType CurrentMode { get; set; } = ModeType.None;
        public PolylineShape CurrentPolyline { get; set; } = null; // Polilinea temporanea
        public bool IsDrawingPolyline { get; set; } = false; // Flag per il disegno polilinea
        
        private Point currentCursorPoint; // Posizione corrente del cursore
        private Point? startPoint = null; // Punto iniziale del disegno
        private IShape tempShape = null; // Forma temporanea
        private Point? selectedHandler = null; // Handler selezionato per modifica
        private bool isDragging = false; // Flag per indicare il trascinamento
        private Point dragStartPoint; // Punto iniziale del trascinamento
        private Point? activeResizeHandler = null; // Handler attivo per il resize
        private int selectedResizeHandler; // Handler selezionato per il resize
        // --------

        // ------------ AREA DI MISURA PANNELLO
        public event EventHandler<ShapeChangedEventArgs> ShapeChanged;
        public event EventHandler ThermalImageUpdated;
        // -----------

        // --------- MOSTRA PUNTO CALDO GLOBALE
        public bool ShowHotSpot { get; set; } = false;
        private readonly PointShape _hotSpot = new PointShape();
        // ---------

        private bool _disposed = false;
        private Rectangle _imageBounds;
        private readonly ToolTip _toolTip = new ToolTip();

        private Bitmap _paletteImage = null;
        public Bitmap PaletteImage
        {
            get => _paletteImage;
            set
            {
                Image = _paletteImage = value;
                CalculateImageBounds();
            }
        }

        public ushort[,] ThermalImage { get; set; } = null;
        public EvoIRFrameMetadata Metadata { get; set; }

        public RadiometricImage()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("RadiometricImage created.");

            BackColor = Color.Black;
            Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            DoubleBuffered = true;
            SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;

            Resize += (s, e) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Resize event triggered.");
                CalculateImageBounds();
            };

            MouseMove += RadiometricImage_MouseMove;
            MouseLeave += RadiometricImage_MouseLeave;

            MouseDown += RadiometricImage_MouseDown;
            MouseUp += RadiometricImage_MouseUp;
            
            
            Paint += RadiometricImage_Paint;
        }

        internal void UpdateRadiometricImage(ThermalPaletteImage img)
        {
            PaletteImage = img.PaletteImage;
            Metadata = img.IRFrameMetadata;
            ThermalImage = img.ThermalImage;
            
            ThermalImageUpdated?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty); // Notifica il cambiamento
        }

        private void RadiometricImage_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Mouse fouri dall'immagine, nascondo tooltip");
            _toolTip.Hide(this);
        }

        private void RadiometricImage_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            if (ShowHotSpot)
            {
                int maxI = 0, maxJ = 0;
                ushort max = ThermalImage[0, 0];

                for (int i = 0; i < ThermalImage.GetLength(0); ++i)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < ThermalImage.GetLength(1); ++j)
                    {
                        if (ThermalImage[i, j] > max)
                        {
                            max = ThermalImage[i, j];
                            maxI = i;
                            maxJ = j;
                        }
                    }
                }

                _hotSpot.Position = new Point(maxJ, maxI);
                _hotSpot.Name = $"{Conversion.RealTemperatureValue(max)} °C";
                _hotSpot.Draw(e.Graphics, FromImageToContainer, Color.Black);
                DrawShapeName(e.Graphics, _hotSpot, Color.Black);
            }


            foreach (var shape in Shapes)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("shape");

                shape.Draw(e.Graphics, FromImageToContainer);
                DrawShapeName(e.Graphics, shape);
                if (SelectedShapes.Contains(shape))
                {
                    DrawShapeHandlers(e.Graphics, shape);
                }
            }

            if (ShapeToDraw == ShapeType.Polyline && CurrentPolyline != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("polyline shape");
                CurrentPolyline.Draw(e.Graphics, FromImageToContainer);
                DrawPolylinePreview(e.Graphics);
                DrawShapeHandlers(e.Graphics, CurrentPolyline);
            }

            tempShape?.Draw(e.Graphics, FromImageToContainer);
        }

        internal void RadiometricImage_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Delete)
            {
                if (SelectedShapes.Any())
                {
                    foreach (var shape in SelectedShapes.ToList())
                    {
                        RemoveShape(shape);
                    }

                    SelectedShapes.Clear();
                    Invalidate();
                }
            }
            else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Escape)
            {
                ResetDrawingState();
                Invalidate();
            }

            if (SelectedShapes.Any())
            {
                const int moveStep = 1;
                switch (e.KeyCode)
                {
                    case Keys.Left:
                        MoveSelectedShapes(new Point(-moveStep, 0), true);
                        break;
                    case Keys.Right:
                        MoveSelectedShapes(new Point(moveStep, 0), true);
                        break;
                    case Keys.Up:
                        MoveSelectedShapes(new Point(0, -moveStep), true);
                        break;
                    case Keys.Down:
                        MoveSelectedShapes(new Point(0, moveStep), true);
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

        private void RadiometricImage_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"MouseUp at {e.Location}");

            if (isDragging)
            {
                isDragging = false;
                Cursor = Cursors.Default;
            }
            else if (activeResizeHandler.HasValue)
            {
                activeResizeHandler = null;
                Cursor = Cursors.Default;
            }
            else if ((ShapeToDraw == ShapeType.Rectangle || ShapeToDraw == ShapeType.Ellipse) && tempShape != null)
            {
                tempShape.Name = $"Area {Shapes.Count + 1}";
                AddShape(tempShape);
                tempShape = null;
                startPoint = null;
            }
            selectedHandler = null;
            Cursor = Cursors.Default;
            
            
            // Invalidate();
        }

        private void RadiometricImage_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"MouseMove at {e.Location}");

            if (CurrentMode == ModeType.None && _imageBounds.Contains(e.Location))
            {
                var position = FromContainerToImage(e.Location);
                double temperature = CameraService.GetPixelValue(ThermalImage, position);
                _toolTip.Show($"{temperature} °C", this, e.X + 10, e.Y + 10);
            }
            else
            {
                _toolTip.Hide(this);
            }

            currentCursorPoint = e.Location;
            
            if (activeResizeHandler.HasValue && SelectedShapes.Count == 1 && activeResizeHandler.Value != e.Location)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Active Handler: {activeResizeHandler.Value}");
                var shape = SelectedShapes.First();
                if (_imageBounds.Contains(e.Location))
                {

                    shape.Resize(FromContainerToImage(activeResizeHandler.Value), FromContainerToImage(e.Location)); // Ridimensiona la forma
                    var aux = shape.GetHandlers();
                    activeResizeHandler = FromImageToContainer(aux.ElementAt(selectedResizeHandler)); // Aggiorna la posizione dell'handler
                    Invalidate();
                }

            }
            else if (isDragging && SelectedShapes.Any())
            {
                MoveSelectedShapes(e.Location);
                dragStartPoint = e.Location;
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (var shape in SelectedShapes)
                {
                    var pos = FromContainerToImage(e.Location);
                    bool onHandler = false;
                    if (shape is PolylineShape polyline)
                    {
                        foreach (var handler in polyline.GetHandlers())
                        {
                            if (DrawHelper.IsCloseToPoint(e.Location, FromImageToContainer(handler)))
                            {
                                Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
                                onHandler = true;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else if (!(shape is PointShape point))
                    {
                        foreach (var handler in shape.GetHandlers())
                        {
                            if (DrawHelper.IsCloseToPoint(e.Location, FromImageToContainer(handler)))
                            {
                                Cursor = DrawHelper.GetResizeCursor(handler, shape); // Ottieni il cursore corretto
                                onHandler = true;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if (!onHandler)
                    {
                        Cursor = Cursors.Default;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (CurrentMode == ModeType.Draw)
            {
                if (ShapeToDraw == ShapeType.Polyline && selectedHandler.HasValue) MovePolylineHandler(FromContainerToImage(e.Location));
                if ((ShapeToDraw == ShapeType.Rectangle || ShapeToDraw == ShapeType.Ellipse) && startPoint.HasValue) UpdateTemporaryShape(e.Location);

                Invalidate();
            }
        } 


        private void RadiometricImage_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"MouseDown at {e.Location}");

            if (CurrentMode == ModeType.Select)
            {
                HandleSelectionMouseDown(e.Location);
                if (SelectedShapes.Any() && isDragging)
                {
                    Cursor = Cursors.SizeAll;
                }
            }
            
            if (CurrentMode == ModeType.Draw)
            {
                if (_imageBounds.Contains(e.Location))
                {
                    switch (ShapeToDraw)
                    {
                        case ShapeType.Point:
                            AddPointShape(e.Location);
                            break;
                        case ShapeType.Rectangle:
                        case ShapeType.Ellipse:
                            startPoint = FromContainerToImage(e.Location);
                            break;
                        case ShapeType.Polyline:
                            HandlePolylineMouseDown(e);
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }


        public void AddShape(IShape shape)
        {
            Shapes.Add(shape);
            OnShapeAdded(shape);
            Invalidate(); // Per ridisegnare shape.GetRegion(FromImageToContainer)
        }

        public void RemoveShape(IShape shape)
        {
            if (Shapes.Remove(shape))
            {
                OnShapeRemoved(shape);
                Invalidate(); // Per ridisegnare shape.GetRegion(FromImageToContainer)
            }
        }

        #region HELPERS

        private Point FromContainerToImage(Point src)
        {
            if (Image == null) return Point.Empty;

            float xRatio = (float)(src.X - _imageBounds.Left) / _imageBounds.Width;
            float yRatio = (float)(src.Y - _imageBounds.Top) / _imageBounds.Height;

            return new Point((int)(xRatio * Image.Width), (int)(yRatio * Image.Height));
        }

        private Point FromImageToContainer(Point src)
        {
            if (Image == null) return Point.Empty;

            float xRatio = (float)src.X / Image.Width;
            float yRatio = (float)src.Y / Image.Height;

            return new Point((int)(xRatio * _imageBounds.Width + _imageBounds.Left), (int)(yRatio * _imageBounds.Height + _imageBounds.Top));
        }

        private void CalculateImageBounds()
        {
            if (Image == null)
            {
                _imageBounds = new Rectangle(0, 0, 0, 0);
                return;
            }

            float xRatio = (float)Width / Image.Width;
            float yRatio = (float)Height / Image.Height;

            float ratio = Math.Min(xRatio, yRatio);

            int width = (int)(Image.Width * ratio);
            int height = (int)(Image.Height * ratio);

            _imageBounds = new Rectangle((Width - width) / 2, (Height - height) / 2, width, height);
        }

        private void DrawHandler(Graphics g, Point point)
        {
            const int size = 10;
            var rect = new Rectangle(point.X - size / 2, point.Y - size / 2, size, size);
            using (var brush = new SolidBrush(SystemColors.Highlight))
            {
                g.FillRectangle(brush, rect);
            }
        }

        private void DrawShapeHandlers(Graphics g, IShape shape)
        {
            foreach (var handler in shape.GetHandlers().Select(x => FromImageToContainer(x)))
            {
                DrawHandler(g, handler);
            }
        }

        private void ResetDrawingState()
        {
            if (ShapeToDraw == ShapeType.Polyline && IsDrawingPolyline)
            {
                CurrentPolyline = null;
                IsDrawingPolyline = false;
            }
            else if ((ShapeToDraw == ShapeType.Rectangle || ShapeToDraw == ShapeType.Ellipse) && tempShape != null)
            {
                tempShape = null;
                startPoint = null;
            }
            else if (SelectedShapes.Any())
            {
                SelectedShapes.Clear();
            }

            // CurrentMode = ModeType.None;
        }

        private void HandlePolylineMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (CurrentPolyline != null)
            {
                var point = FromContainerToImage(e.Location);

                if (CurrentPolyline.Points.Count > 0 && DrawHelper.IsCloseToPoint(point, CurrentPolyline.Points[0]))
                {
                    CurrentPolyline.ClosePolyline();
                    CurrentPolyline.IsClosed = true;
                    CurrentPolyline.Name = $"Area {Shapes.Count + 1}";
                    AddShape(CurrentPolyline);
                    CurrentPolyline = null;
                    IsDrawingPolyline = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    CurrentPolyline.Points.Add(point);
                }
            }
        }

        private void AddPointShape(Point location)
        {
            var pointShape = new PointShape() { Name = $"Area {Shapes.Count + 1}", Position = FromContainerToImage(location) };
            AddShape(pointShape);
        }

        private void UpdateTemporaryShape(Point location)
        {
            if (startPoint.HasValue && _imageBounds.Contains(location))
            {
                var rect = DrawHelper.GetRectangleFromPoints(startPoint.Value, FromContainerToImage(location));
                switch (ShapeToDraw)
                {
                    case ShapeType.Rectangle:
                        tempShape = new RectangleShape { Rect = rect };
                        break;
                    case ShapeType.Ellipse:
                        tempShape = new EllipseShape { Bounds = rect };
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

        private void MoveSelectedShapes(Point location, bool keyboard = false)
        {
            var bounds = new Rectangle(0, 0, Image.Width, Image.Height);
            if (keyboard)
            {
                foreach (var shape in SelectedShapes)
                {
                    shape.Move(bounds, location);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                var convertedLocation = FromContainerToImage(location);
                var convartedStartPoint = FromContainerToImage(dragStartPoint);

                var deltaX = convertedLocation.X - convartedStartPoint.X;
                var deltaY = convertedLocation.Y - convartedStartPoint.Y;

                foreach (var shape in SelectedShapes)
                {
                    shape.Move(bounds, new Point(deltaX, deltaY));
                }
                dragStartPoint = location;
            }
        }

        private void MovePolylineHandler(Point location)
        {
            if (CurrentPolyline != null && selectedHandler.HasValue)
            {
                var index = CurrentPolyline.Points.IndexOf(selectedHandler.Value);
                if (index >= 0)
                {
                    CurrentPolyline.Points[index] = location;
                }
            }
        }

        private void DrawShapeName(Graphics g, IShape shape, Color color = default)
        {
            var center = shape.NamePosition(FromImageToContainer, Image.Height);

            if (color == default) color = Color.White;

            using (var font = new Font("Arial", 14))
            {
                using (var brush = new SolidBrush(color))
                {
                    g.DrawString(shape.Name, font, brush, center);
                }
            }
        }

        private void HandleSelectionMouseDown(Point location)
        {
            SelectedShapes.Clear();
            activeResizeHandler = null; // Resetta l'handler attivo
            
            foreach (var shape in Shapes)
            {
                if (!(shape is PointShape point))
                {
                    int i = 0;
                    foreach (var handler in shape.GetHandlers())
                    {
                        var h = FromImageToContainer(handler);
                        if (DrawHelper.IsCloseToPoint(location, h))
                        {
                            SelectedShapes.Add(shape);
                            activeResizeHandler = h; // Memorizza l'handler attivo per il resize
                            selectedResizeHandler = i;
                            Console.WriteLine($"Handler: {h}");
                            return;
                        }
                        i++;
                    }
                }
                if (shape.PointOnBound(FromContainerToImage(location)))
                {
                    SelectedShapes.Add(shape);
                    dragStartPoint = location;
                    isDragging = true;
                    Invalidate();
                    return;
                }
            }
        }

        private void DrawPolylinePreview(Graphics g)
        {
            if (CurrentPolyline != null && CurrentPolyline.Points.Count > 0)
            {
                var lastPoint = CurrentPolyline.Points.Last();
                if (DrawHelper.IsCloseToPoint(FromContainerToImage(currentCursorPoint), CurrentPolyline.Points[0]))
                {
                    g.DrawLine(Pens.White, FromImageToContainer(lastPoint), FromImageToContainer(CurrentPolyline.Points[0]));
                }
                else
                {
                    g.DrawLine(Pens.Gray, FromImageToContainer(lastPoint), currentCursorPoint);
                }
            }
        }

        #endregion

        #region AREA_DI_MISURA

        private void OnShapeAdded(IShape shape)
        {
            ShapeChanged?.Invoke(this, new ShapeChangedEventArgs(shape, AreaOperation.Added));
        }

        private void OnShapeRemoved(IShape shape)
        {
            ShapeChanged?.Invoke(this, new ShapeChangedEventArgs(shape, AreaOperation.Removed));
        }

        #endregion

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (!_disposed)
            {
                if (disposing)
                {
                    if (PaletteImage != null)
                    {
                        PaletteImage.Dispose();
                        PaletteImage = null;
                    }

                    if (Shapes != null)
                    {
                        Shapes.Clear();
                        Shapes = null;
                    }

                    if (SelectedShapes != null)
                    {
                        SelectedShapes.Clear();
                        SelectedShapes = null;
                    }

                    if (ThermalImage != null) ThermalImage = null;
                    if (CurrentPolyline != null) CurrentPolyline = null;

                    Resize -= (s, e) => CalculateImageBounds();
                    MouseMove -= RadiometricImage_MouseMove;
                    MouseDown -= RadiometricImage_MouseDown;
                    MouseUp -= RadiometricImage_MouseUp;
                    Paint -= RadiometricImage_Paint;
                }
            }

            base.Dispose(disposing);

            _disposed = true;
        }
    }
}

The code works, but when the streaming from the camera is in high definition or there are many shapes drawn, the whole application slows down causing inconvenience to the user. Do you have any advice and suggestions to give me to optimize this component at best?

The first rule of optimization is to measure. We can make guesses about why the code is slow all day, but a running a profiler will actually tell you where the problems are.
I cannot see where the code to convert the 16 bit values down to 8 bit values is. But this is one area of concern, and you probably want to cache the result of this conversion to speed up redraws.

for (int i = 0; i < ThermalImage.GetLength(0); ++i)

.GetLength is quite slow, and should not be called for every pixel. I would recommend not using multi dimensional arrays at all for image data, since these stores pixels in column major format, in contrast to row major that just about every other image format uses. My recommendation would be to use a 1D array, and do the indexing yourself, i.e. [y * width + x].

Sorry, maybe I should have specified, the camera is a thermal camera, so when I get the Bitmap I also get the matrix with the pixel values. However, I tried profiling the memory with MemoryPeek but I can't quite figure out what methods are involved. Should the _Paint method the problem?

@th3g3ntl3man I figured that out. The thermal cameras I work with require you to do the ushort->byte conversion yourself. But if that is handled by a library it is probably fine. See Measure app performance in Visual Studio for an introduction to profiling. You probably want to start with a performance profiler and not a memory profiler, unless you suspect memory leaks.
